# Need two balls to display simultaneously , only 1 ball appears VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am creating a program so that two balls are instantiated on the same display and they are bouncing off the sides of the display. To ensure they do not happen at the same location, I added a Generic constant for the x and y locations and mapped that for each ball. In this case, I am okay with hard coding it (no loops needed as I just want 2 balls to appear)

I am very stuck as I can only get 1 ball to appear even when I instantiated two vga_sync.

The vga_top.vhd

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

ENTITY vga_top IS
    GENERIC (
        initial_x1 : INTEGER := 400;
        initial_y1 : INTEGER := 300;
        initial_x2 : INTEGER := 300;
        initial_y2 : INTEGER := 200;
        initial_x3 : INTEGER := 100;
        initial_y3 : INTEGER := 100
    );
    PORT (
        clk_in    : IN STD_LOGIC;
        vga_red   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 DOWNTO 0);
        vga_green : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 DOWNTO 0);
        vga_blue  : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 DOWNTO 0);
        vga_hsync,vga_hsync2  : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        vga_vsync, vga_vsync2 : OUT STD_LOGIC
    );

END vga_top;

ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF vga_top IS
    SIGNAL pxl_clk : STD_LOGIC;
    -- internal signals to connect modules
    SIGNAL S_red, S_green, S_blue : STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL S_red2, S_green2, S_blue2 : STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL S_red3, S_green3, S_blue3 : STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL S_vsync : STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL S_pixel_row, S_pixel_col : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL S_pixel_row2, S_pixel_col2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 DOWNTO 0); -- Separate signals for the second ball
    SIGNAL S_pixel_row3, S_pixel_col3 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 DOWNTO 0);
    

    COMPONENT ball IS
        GENERIC (
            initial_x: INTEGER;
            initial_y: INTEGER
        );
        PORT (
            v_sync : IN STD_LOGIC;
            pixel_row : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(10 DOWNTO 0);
            pixel_col : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(10 DOWNTO 0);
            red : OUT STD_LOGIC;
            green : OUT STD_LOGIC;
            blue : OUT STD_LOGIC
        );
    END COMPONENT;

    COMPONENT vga_sync IS
        PORT (
            pixel_clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
            red_in    : IN STD_LOGIC;
            green_in  : IN STD_LOGIC;
            blue_in   : IN STD_LOGIC;
            red_out   : OUT STD_LOGIC;
            green_out : OUT STD_LOGIC;
            blue_out  : OUT STD_LOGIC;
            hsync     : OUT STD_LOGIC;
            vsync     : OUT STD_LOGIC;
            pixel_row : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 DOWNTO 0);
            pixel_col : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 DOWNTO 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;

    component clk_wiz_0 is
        port (
            clk_in1  : in std_logic;
            clk_out1 : out std_logic
        );
    end component;

BEGIN
    -- vga_driver only drives MSB of red, green & blue
    -- so set other bits to zero

    vga_red(1 DOWNTO 0) <= "00";
    vga_green(1 DOWNTO 0) <= "00";
    vga_blue(0) <= '0';

    add_ball1 : ball
        GENERIC MAP (
            initial_x => initial_x1,
            initial_y => initial_y1
        )
        PORT MAP (
            v_sync    => S_vsync,
            pixel_row => S_pixel_row,
            pixel_col => S_pixel_col,
            red       => S_red,
            green     => S_green,
            blue      => S_blue
        );

    add_ball2 : ball
        GENERIC MAP (
            initial_x => initial_x2,
            initial_y => initial_y2
        )
        PORT MAP (
            v_sync    => S_vsync,
            pixel_row => S_pixel_row2,
            pixel_col => S_pixel_col2,
            red       => S_red2,
            green     => S_green2,
            blue      => S_blue2
        );

    add_ball3 : ball
        GENERIC MAP (
            initial_x => initial_x3,
            initial_y => initial_y3
        )
        PORT MAP (
            v_sync    => S_vsync,
            pixel_row => S_pixel_row3,
            pixel_col => S_pixel_col3,
            red       => S_red3,
            green     => S_green3,
            blue      => S_blue3
        );


    vga_driver : vga_sync
        PORT MAP (
            --instantiate vga_sync component
            pixel_clk => pxl_clk,
            red_in    => S_red,
            green_in  => S_green,
            blue_in   => S_blue,
            red_out   => vga_red(2),
            green_out => vga_green(2),
            blue_out  => vga_blue(1),
            pixel_row => S_pixel_row,   -- Use separate signals for the first ball
            pixel_col => S_pixel_col    -- Use separate signals for the first ball
        );
        
            vga_driver2 : vga_sync
        PORT MAP (
            --instantiate vga_sync component for ball 2
            pixel_clk => pxl_clk,
            red_in    => S_red2,
            green_in  => S_green2,
            blue_in   => S_blue2,
            red_out   => vga_red(1),   -- You can assign different bits if needed
            green_out => vga_green(1), -- You can assign different bits if needed
            blue_out  => vga_blue(0),  -- You can assign different bits if needed
            pixel_row => S_pixel_row2,
            pixel_col => S_pixel_col2,
            hsync     => vga_hsync2,
            vsync     => S_vsync
        );


    vga_vsync <= S_vsync; --connect output vsync

    clk_wiz_0_inst : clk_wiz_0
    port map (
        clk_in1   => clk_in,
        clk_out1  => pxl_clk
    );

END Behavioral;
```

Ball.vhd

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

ENTITY ball IS
    GENERIC (
        initial_x: INTEGER;
        initial_y: INTEGER
    );
    
    PORT (
        v_sync    : IN STD_LOGIC;
        pixel_row : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(10 DOWNTO 0);
        pixel_col : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(10 DOWNTO 0);
        red       : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        green     : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        blue      : OUT STD_LOGIC
    );
END ball;

ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF ball IS
    CONSTANT size  : INTEGER := 8;
    
    --BALL1
    SIGNAL ball_on : STD_LOGIC; -- indicates whether ball is over current pixel position
    -- current ball position - initialized to center of screen
    SIGNAL ball_x  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(10 DOWNTO 0) := CONV_STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(initial_x, 11);
    SIGNAL ball_y  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(10 DOWNTO 0) := CONV_STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(initial_y, 11);
    -- current ball motion - initialized to +4 pixels/frame
    SIGNAL ball_y_motion : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(10 DOWNTO 0) := "00000000100";
    SIGNAL ball_x_motion : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(10 DOWNTO 0) := "00000000100";
    
BEGIN

    red <= NOT ball_on; -- color setup for red ball on white background
    green <= '1';
    blue  <= NOT ball_on;
    -- process to draw ball current pixel address is covered by ball position
    bdraw : PROCESS (ball_x, ball_y, pixel_row, pixel_col) IS
    BEGIN
        IF (pixel_col >= ball_x - size) AND
         (pixel_col <= ball_x + size) AND
             (pixel_row >= ball_y - size) AND
             (pixel_row <= ball_y + size) THEN
                ball_on <= '1';
        ELSE
            ball_on <= '0';
        END IF;
        END PROCESS;
        -- process to move ball once every frame (i.e. once every vsync pulse)
        mball : PROCESS
        BEGIN
            WAIT UNTIL rising_edge(v_sync);
            -- allow for bounce off top or bottom of screen
            IF ball_y + size >= 600 THEN
                ball_y_motion <= "11111111100"; -- -4 pixels
            ELSIF ball_x + size >= 800 THEN
                 ball_x_motion <= "11111111100";
            ELSIF ball_x <= size THEN
                ball_x_motion <= "00000000100";          
            ELSIF ball_y <= size THEN
                ball_y_motion <= "00000000100"; -- +4 pixels
            END IF;
            ball_y <= ball_y + ball_y_motion; -- compute next ball position
            ball_x <= ball_x + ball_x_motion;
        END PROCESS;
END Behavioral;
```

I believe it has to do with my vga_sync process as I am not properly combining the pixels from ball 1 and ball2. When I tried combining it and adding it to 1 vga_sync, no ball appears.

```
   combined_red <= S_red or S_red2;
    combined_green <= S_green or S_green2;
    combined_blue <= S_blue or S_blue2;
```

```
  vga_driver : vga_sync
    PORT MAP(
        --instantiate vga_sync component
      pixel_clk => pxl_clk, 
        red_in    => combined_red, 
        green_in  => combined_green, 
        blue_in   => combined_blue, 
        red_out   => vga_red(2), 
        green_out => vga_green(2), 
        blue_out  => vga_blue(1), 
        pixel_row => S_pixel_row, 
        pixel_col => S_pixel_col, 
        hsync     => vga_hsync, 
        vsync     => S_vsync
    );
```

Could you please assist?

Answer (score -2):

The ball entity is designed to draw a green ball on a white background:

```
red <= NOT ball_on;
green <= '1';
blue  <= NOT ball_on;
```

You will need to rethink your combination statements, you're currently using the *or* operator, which does not do what you want here.

If you're not sure why you'll need to change the combination statement operator, try instead changing the color output of the ball entity to use a black background, it should work with the *or* operator:

```
red <= '0';
green <= ball_on;
blue  <= '0';
```